# Conditional statement in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

I am writing a stored procedure in which such as a in update statement but ma confuse how to apply such type of thing?

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Payment_SP]
    @reciptId varchar(50)=null,
    @balPay float=null,
    @payDone float=null,
    @payDate datetime=null,
    @fullfillId_FK varchar(50)=null,
    @clintId_FK int=null,
    @status varchar(50)=null,
    @operation int,
    @fullfillId varchar(50)=null
AS
BEGIN   
    if @operation = 3
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Recipt 
        SET balPay = @balPay 
        WHERE reciptId = @reciptId

        if @@rowcount = 0
            insert into Recipt(reciptId, balPay, payDone, payDate, fullfillId_FK, clintId_FK)
            values(@reciptId, @balPay, @payDone, @payDate, @fullfillId_FK, @clintId_FK)
        update Item_Full 
        set totCost = (select balPay from Recipt) 
        where fullfillId = @reciptId

        if @balPay='0'
        BEGIN
            update Item_Order 
            set status = 'CLOSE' 
            where status = 'FULLFILL' 
               or status = 'RUNNING' 
              and orderId = @reciptId
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            update Item_Order 
            set status = 'RUNING' 
            where status = 'FULLFILL' 
              and orderId = @reciptId
        END
    END
END
```

Here I am using plenty of tables and columns. But what I want to do that in `Recipt` table if balance payment (@balPay = 0) then the status = CLOSE otherwise if there is any balance > 0 then status = RUNING

But each time I get status is `RUNING` after payment done. This means only else part of the conditional statement is executing not if part

What should be condition there in if statement

Thank you

Comment: Without seeing the parameters you're passing in, it's hard to tell.  This update statement looks wrong, though:  `update Item_Order set status='CLOSE' where status='FULLFILL' or status='RUNNING' and     orderId=@reciptId`.  You don't have your `OR` statements grouped together like this:  `update Item_Order set status='CLOSE' where (status='FULLFILL' or status='RUNNING') and     orderId=@reciptId`

Comment: i follow your instructions but the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

@balPay never gets updated from null, so your else statement is always executed.

Comment: `NULL` is the default value for `@balPay`.  If any value is passed in, it will use that value instead, assuming a value is passed in.

Comment: i remove null as a default value of @balPay but  the problem is same

Comment: is this value being passed in? What happens when you run the stored proc in a local query window?

Comment: Are you able to debug and catch the params that are going into your SP from your application? Do you get the same result running your SP with those params in sql server management studio?

Comment: yes....everything is doing well...the problem is that what i describe earlier  nothing else..

Answer (score 0):

ok guys there was a silly spelling mistake i have done that is i change status in else  RUNING  and  if condition looking for RUNNING ...sorry and thanks